# Text-align: center wont's apply to a link after an image

Tags: html, css

I found the way to make a link to align, if I do the break between img and the link.

```html
<section id="home" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526374965328-7f61d4dc18c5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80);">
  <h1>It's my super wooper page</h1>
  <img class="profile-picture" src="assets/img/My_Picture.JPG" alt="picture of myself">
  <br>
  <a class="btn-cv" href="#">Download CV</a>
</section>
```

The question is WHY the link won't just align, as it is a text-element. And what is even more "weird", the margin won't work for the link, so it keeps sticking to the image. I know, I could give the image some `margin-bottom`, but I's really like to understand, what is happening in the backgrond.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align the link in the center. You should put `text-align: center;` on the parent element and not on the `<a>`. It's because the `<a>` is an inline element.

Comment: I know. Text is aligned to the center in  #home but the link won't align. That is why I was really not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. `<a>` is an inline element. if you are applying a `margin` to `<a>` tag then you need to give `display:inline-block` property to `<a>`

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/pt68qczy/

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-cv {
  margin: 10px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section id="home" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526374965328-7f61d4dc18c5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80);">
  <h1>It's my super wooper page</h1>
  <img class="profile-picture" src="assets/img/My_Picture.JPG" alt="picture of myself">
  <br>
  <div class="text-center">
    <a class="btn-cv" href="#">Download CV</a>
  </div>
</section>
```